# php mysql avoid multiple/duplicate insertions from a single insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert one row into a sample table. But every time I run the webpage, multiple rows are getting inserted. When I execute the same query from phpmyadmin, I get only one row inserted, which is right. I've also tried IGNORE and setting a primary key.

[image: DB Table Structure that am using]

The following is a snippet of the insert code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "admin";
$dbname = "learnphp";
//connection open
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
//testing for connection error
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Databse connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error()."(".mysqli_connect_errno().")");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Insert into Database with php</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$id = 1;
$name = 'sam';
$age  = 10;

$query = "INSERT INTO first (id,name,age) VALUES ('{id}','{$name}', '{$age}')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if($result)
{
    //Success
    //redirect_to("somepage.php");
    echo "Success".$result;
}
else
{
    //Failure
    //$message = "inserttion failed";
    die("Database query failed.".mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    //connection close
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: sounds like you have a loop somewhere in your php code...

Comment: Show the code above the $query

Comment: Please provide more code. The problem is not of insert code. In other code it is calling insert query more than once.

Comment: If you're using `mysqli`, you **must** use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to assign those values to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to do this, you will create gigantic [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Mihai: I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: If you put a unique constraint on a column that doesn't autoincrement it will be physically impossible to insert duplicate data

Comment: @Parixit: I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: @Tim: I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: @ChrisPetrus Code seems perfect! When you open the page in browser it add record twice?

Comment: @ChrisPetrus Is your problem persist? Can you tell me which browser you are using?

Comment: @Parixit Yes that's the problem. Sometimes there are more than two entries also. And I am using Chrome.

Comment: @Parixit I've also tried in Firefox and IE, but the problem still persists. So I tried the same code in my friend's system and it worked correctly. Am using XAMPP on Windows. So guess the problem is in configuring those things. Only insert query is causing a problem. Other queries are working fine.

Comment: @ChrisPetrus Yes configuration might cause problem. Also note that when you are typing URL in address bar of chrome then also chrome send a request to that page. So it also cause problem. But if problem is in other browsers as well then you should have to check XAMPP or re install it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your code is getting executed twice.  I am guessing your page has some sort of refresh or header changed.  Try placing an exit; after the echo "Success" and see if only one row is inserted.  I am guessing that will be the case.